# What is the cleanest way to include and access binary data in VC++ Express?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have some binary files that I'd like to embed in a dll I'm compiling with VC++ Express Edition.

I have a couple ways to do it (like converting the data to arrays that I compile along with the code), but I'm not satisfied and I feel like I'm probably missing an easy, straightforward solution.

What's the cleanest, easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if this is an option, but the Unix (and probably easily avaliable on Windows) program `xxd` has an option to output a C header:

```
xxd -i file.bin > file.h
```

`file.h` will contain the definition of an array of `unsigned char` containing the data and an `unsigned int` that tells you the length of the array. Of course, it may be better to output to `file.c` and then write `file.h` as:

```
extern unsigned char file[];
extern unsigned int file_len;
```

The names of the variables depend on the input file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Heh. Google Desktop Searched my hard drive and I already have xxd! Came with Vim. Thanks!

Comment: The resources answer given by Vinay Sajip is closer to what I was asking for, but using xxd is so easy I decided to chuck the custom code I had written and use it instead. If my files were bigger, I might choose the binary resources.

Answer (score 2):

The last time I had to do this (some while ago) I used binary resources. Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/binaryresources.aspx) which describes the approach. I'm not sure if there's anything more recent which does it better, though.